# How can fprintf block in Linux?

Tags: linux, io, buffer, block, stdio

I have a `fprintf` call which blocked for about unreasonable 10 seconds when the system is IO busy but still has lots of CPU. I neither `setvbuf` of the underlying stream nor opened the underlying fd with `O_DIRECT`. This means the stream has both stdio stream and system cache.

I cannot tell how can a `fprintf` call get blocked for such a long period.  For the worst case in which the stream buffer of the underlying stream is full, I think the libc just call `write(2)` to write the buffer content to disk.  But to my knowledge, `write(2)` on an fd that is not opened with `O_DIRECT` will not wait for the disk transfer, i.e. it is asynchronous as to disk IO.  So the only time consuming work I could think of is the kernel's allocating cache for the written data, but this does not seem like a 10-second work even when the system is lack of memory.  In fact, the system has tens of MB of free memory and several GB of memory cached.

Is there any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the size of the transferred data ?

Comment: About 100 Bytes, I was just writing log.

Comment: not opening with o_direct does not means it would be finished quickly.. it can be dealing with, for example, cache/lock contention.

Comment: Possible, especially when the IO is busy.

Comment: By writing into a named pipe, fprintf can block for any time, waiting for another process to read the data. So it's not exactly fprintf that is blocking, it's the write operation.

Comment: ammoQ, I was writing to a disk file, is there any case in which a write operation get blocked for a long period of time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your code on more than one machine? If so, the behaviour is the same?

If not, check for disk access errors in your system's log, once I had a similar problem and the reason was a faulty disk.

Comment: Actually, I have tens of servers suffering from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A write call is not asynchronous, ie the system call must return from the kernel.
Of course this system call, is mainly putting data on a I/O queue, that will do the real transfer later. However, I guess this I/O queue may be inacessible for quite some time.

This is independent of the media you are writing to, as long as it is a block device. I have a program writing streams of JPEG images to an SD card. This program will get stuck because of operations taking place on the hard disk.

However, if this is a problem with the write call blocking for ten seconds, you can try to strace your program. I don't know how or if it will disturb the behaviour you try to observe

```
strace -T -e trace=write progname
```

If you want to monitor your log activity, may be you can redirect your log write to a pipe or a named pipe, put a process that is essentially reading from this pipe and writing to your logfile, and strace it.

Comment: Have you finally found the reason why your program which writes SD card get stuck because of hard disk operations?  I think this reason would be helpful.  BTW, I think every block device (not partition) has its own request queue, so it is unlikely for 2 threads contending on queues of different devices.

Comment: Yes, each has its own request queue, but in the end, is not each queue processed through a single scheduler ? It was on a 2.6.24 kernel. May be things have changed since.

Comment: And even if I am wrong, you can trytlog on a tmpfs, and see if your problem disappear

Comment: The problem only occurs at some time on the online servers, and up to now cannot be reproduced on the testing machine, both have the same hardware and system.

Comment: @Utoah : see http://lwn.net/Articles/326552/ for how different block device can block each other. In my understanding at least

Comment: Wonderful article. Nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

You said you didn't call `setvbuf()` on the stream, but what kind of buffering is the stream using?  Unless the stream you're using is `stderr` (or sometimes `stdout`), it will be block buffered by default, which means that no writes will happen until the buffer is full (typically 4096 bytes or more).  Depending on how frequently you are writing logs, this could cause your perceived 10 second delay.

So I would try: `setvbuf(my_stream, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`

**EDIT:** ...Or, it's possible I completely misinterpreted the word "blocked".  Leaving anyway, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

If your process is writing large amounts of data to disk, it will create many dirty pages in the page cache, and `write()` will eventually force your process to do synchronous writeback for some of those pages.  In this situation, the kernel won't return back to your process until it's written out a reasonable amount of data to disk (10 seconds still sounds a little high, though).

Comment: Helpful. It is a busy server and writes lots of log to disk. When some other IO bound program starts on the same server, it is likely to have a 10-second write. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Utoah: Writeback is tunable by sysctls in `/proc/sys/vm/`.  You could try decreasing `dirty_expire_centisecs` and increasing `dirty_ratio` so that more of the writeback work is done in the background.